# Is there a way to type things in WebBrowser in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a webBrowser (`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`) in my windows form,
And I have set the url property to "http://www.google.com", And when I run the solution, it shows google in my form.

My question is, can you programmatically write stuff in the search box?

Do I have access to DOM elements within the webBrowser and can I modify them?

Comment: In short, yes you can.  What have you tried thus far?  A little posted code goes a _very_ long way here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fill out forms without submitting POST in System.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951619/how-to-fill-out-forms-without-submitting-post-in-system-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using the Document property of the WebBrowser control,
something like this should work (not tested)

```
if (webBrowser1.Document == null) return;
var input = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gbqfq")
input.SetAttribute("value","search for foobar");
```

hope this helps!